# Быстрая сортировка по возрастанию c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

У меня есть быстрая сортировка по убыванию , какой будет быстрая сортировка по возрастанию из этого кода ? ( перепробовал все , не получается ).

```
void quickSort1(T* array, long N)
{

    long i = 0, j = N - 1;
    T temp, p;

    p = array[N >> 1];


    do {
        while (array[i] < p) i++;
        while (array[j] > p) j--;

        if (i <= j) {
            temp = array[i]; array[i] = array[j]; array[j] = temp;
            i++; j--;
        }
    } while (i <= j);



    if (j > 0) quickSort1(array, j);
    if (N > i) quickSort1(array + i, N - i);
}
```

Comment: Найдите все места, где вы сравниваете значения типа T, и поменяйте условия на противоположенные.

Comment: К сожалению , все равно вызывается исключение в компиляторе.

Comment: Ну, тогда напишите разработчикам, что в их компиляторе баг :)

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать переделанный фрагмент кода , вы бы очень мне помогли.

Comment: [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: [тык2](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Да не , я видел такие сортировки и много других , но мне интересно именная моя версия ( адаптированная из с). Можно было просто загуглить ,  и там выбило бы десятки быстрых сортировок по возрастанию или убыванию , но мне конкретно интересна моя.

Comment: В большинстве для нахождения среднего элемента используется первый и последний элемент ( у меня же находится средний простым разбиением). Этим и интересна конкретно этот кусок кода.

Comment: Приведенный вами код *НЕ* сортирует. Ну, или, вернее, сортирует неверно. Ну вот, например: https://ideone.com/ZGnVZP И, кстати, средний ли элемент вы берете, первый или последний — алгоритму это все равно. Лучше от этого он не становится...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с исправления вашего алгоритма. Это несложно:

```
if (j > 0) quickSort1(array, j+1);
```

Подумайте-ка, почему `+1`, о чем вы забыли?

После этого получить обратную сортировку совсем легко:

```
while (array[i] > p) i++;
while (array[j] < p) j--;
```

Пример работы см. [тут](https://ideone.com/XgUFmK).

Comment: Минусатор, поясните, в чем конкретно я неправ?

Comment: Большое спасибо , к радости , утром я сам разобрался. j+1 нужен для захвата в сортировке элементов в середине. Как раз перед заходом сюда закончил проект , и он иногда не сортировал средние элементы , после этой доработки все работает , как часы.